# Permission directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I want to have a directive that checks permission.
So that I coud do this:

```
<a permissions="something.delete">Delete</a>
```

If "something.delete" in the list of allowed permissions then nothing is rendered.

Having this code:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   var permissionsPromise = PermissionService.checkForPermissions(attrs.permissions);

   permissionsPromise.then(function(result) {
     if (result=== false) {
        element.remove();
     }
  })
}
```

But because `PermissionService.checkForPermissions()` returns promise, so it may take some time to figure out the permissions, meanwhile link function will render the a-element before knowing the result of permission-check.

What would be the proper solution to fix that issue?

Comment: Reverse your logic and hide the element by default and then show it based on the promise value.

Comment: I thought abut it.. But If I want it not to be hidden but not existing at all.

Comment: Ask yourself what is your real goal, as you aren't really implementing permissions checking on the client-side (or you shouldn't be). This should be more to provide the user with the correct UI experience. If you want to remove it altogether then just keep a reference to the parent element, remove the element, and when your promise returns append it back to the parent .. or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse your logic and hide the element by default and then show it based on the promise value.

something along the lines of elem[0].style.display = 'none' -> elem[0].style.display = 'block'

Ask yourself what is your real goal, as you aren't really implementing permissions checking on the client-side (or you shouldn't be). This should be more to provide the user with the correct UI experience. If you want to remove it altogether then just keep a reference to the parent element, remove the element, and when your promise returns append it back to the parent .. or not.